# image is showing last instead of what is being clicked on

Tags: swift, master-detail

I have a Master-Detail app where it shows images of flowers from Master table view.  I want to show a bigger image in Detail view but it keeps on showing the last image.

DetailViewController is showing an image from the MasterViewController as the last image.  No matter what is being clicked on in MasterViewController, the image showing on detail is the last image on the list from Master..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     imageView1.image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.flowerImage!.first
```

In MasterViewController.swift file, here's the code:

```
override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                             for: indexPath)

    //cell.textLabel!.text = siteNames![indexPath.row]

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case kRedSection:
    do {   cell.textLabel!.text = redFlowers[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = siteDetailRed![indexPath.row]



        }
    case kBlueSection:
        do {
        cell.textLabel!.text = blueFlowers[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = siteDetailBlue![indexPath.row]

        }
    default:
        do {
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Unknown"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Unknown"

        }
    }

    let test = UIImage(named: cell.textLabel!.text!)!
    cell.imageView!.image = test

    MyVariables.flowerImage = [test]
    print("MyVariables.flowerImage", MyVariables.flowerImage)


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of debugged it to this function.  However, it's showing error message fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in this line of code:

```
 MyVariables.flowerImage = [siteImageRed![indexPath.row]]

var siteImageRed: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Gerbera.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "Peony.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "Rose.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "Poppy.png")!
    ]


override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
                      sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            //let urlString = siteAddresses?[indexPath.row]

            switch indexPath.section {
            case 0:
                do {
                    MyVariables.urlString = [siteAddressesRed![indexPath.row]]
                    //why doesn't this line below not work?
                    MyVariables.flowerImage = [siteImageRed![indexPath.row]]
                    //and this line below works?
                    //MyVariables.flowerImage = [UIImage(named: "Rose.png")!]

                }
            case 1:
                do {
                    MyVariables.urlString = [siteAddressesBlue![indexPath.row]]

                }
            default:
                do {
                    MyVariables.urlString = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/flowers"]

                }
            }


            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController
                as! DetailViewController

            controller.detailItem = MyVariables.urlString as [String]! as AnyObject
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
                splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton
                = true
        }
    }
}
```